# Use button click to send message to a node server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

Probably a very naive question but essentially I am interested in what the title says. There is a node server that was created through http.createServer (serverHandler). The server is presenting a webpage that also has a button. So, the question boils down to: how to send a simple json message to the server when the button is clicked. I mean what sort of javascript code do I need on the webpage in order to send a message / http request to the server?

Assume the message is sent to the address "button.json" and hence it will be received by the node server and handled appropriately (say it prints a message through console.log).

Comment: possible dublicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318962/node-js-send-message-to-server

Comment: Two mini observations: 1. I want to use 'http', not 'net'. 2. How does the client know where to find all these packages mentioned in the commands that are 'require'?

Comment: Are you OK with using 3rd party client-side libraries like jQuery or AngularJS?

Comment: @JPRichardson: I guess I can be. I do not know jQuery, so, any pointers in this direction will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodejs server is the same as apache for example. It accepts normal http requests. So, the first thing which you may try is to send ajax requests. Of course you should handle the requests. I.e. creating a route and handler about it. The other method is via web sockets. I.e. establish a socket communication between the front-end code and the nodejs server. There are some libraries which could do that. Like http://socket.io/ for example.

Comment: Thank you for your time. If you could point me to a simple example I would appreciate it. Regarding your link, how would load the client script (/socket.io/socket.io.js) to an arbitrary client who is visiting the server? There's something missing from the picture.

Comment: /socket.io/socket.io.js is served by the server side of the socket.io library. So, you don't have to care about that. Here are an example http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Real-time-chat-with-NodeJS-Socketio-and-ExpressJS

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer and the help. I am voting up right now. In a couple of hours if there is no other response I will accept the answer. Thanks again.